# Is it possible to redirect the user to Firefox browser

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

My current code pops up a warning box window telling the user that he or she is using IE. But is there a way to direct them to Firefox website?

```
public static boolean isIEBrowser()
{
    return (Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().toUpperCase().indexOf("TRIDENT") != -1);
}

if (isIEBrowser())
{
    SC.warn("It looks like you're using a version of Internet Explorer." +
                    " For the best GUI experience, please update your browser.");
 }
```

Comment: Window.Location.replace('youloca')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!

This might be more of what you're looking for.

```
String site = "http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/";
Window.Location.assign(site);
Window.Location.reload();
```

You can also add a simple timer that redirects them after a certain number of seconds or a button that takes them directly to the site.

edit:

Or... you can do this in pure javascript

JS:

```
 function changeURL(site) {
    window.location.href = site;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<script>
   changeURL('http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/');
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason im not seeing the static method assign.. it's there in the Window class. Strange..

Comment: @JennyC Not sure why that is. You might wanna check out the documentation [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html)